# Why does my yarn.lock change even if I don't change my package.json?

Tags: yarnpkg, package.json, yarn-lock.json

After some investigation, I still can't understand why this is happening:

I have a `package.json` file and a `yarn.lock` commited in my repo. If I checkout my `main` branch and run:

```
yarn install
```

I would expect the dependencies from `yarn.lock` to be installed (making my local installation consistent with others).

But for some reason, after running the *install* command, my `yarn.lock` file is changing to this:

[image]

I don't have the **md5** dependency in my `package.json`, but when I run `npm ls md5`, I can see that this is used as a internal dependency in 2 of my packages:

[image]

Why is my `yarn.lock` updating the **md5** dependency when nothing changed in the `package.json`?

Comment: `yarn why <package>` will tell you which other packages depend on that package

Comment: Right...but I still don't understand why my lock file is changing, if I didn't change anything in my package.json